How to make Text in Jetpack Compose to output all LiveData.postValue data without losing old lines
The Text displays only one updated line of Live Data. How to make sure that the text is not overwritten, but Live Data lines are added?
var myLive = MutableLiveData<String>()

setContent {
    val text: String? by myLive.observeAsState()
    text?.let { viewModel.ontextfieldvalChange(it) }

    SelectionContainer {
        Text(
            gameUiState.textfieldval,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Black)
                .height(150.dp)
                .verticalScroll(scroll)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Gray)),
            color = Color.Green,
        )
    }
}

apiWithoutCompose {
    myLive.postValue(link.absUrl("href")
}

Solved:
    fun ontextfieldvalChange(text: String) {
    _gameUiState.update {
        it.copy(textfieldval = it.textfieldval + "\n" + text)
    }
}

Thanks Leviathan

You shouldn't even use LiveData in the first place. With Kotlin and Compose it is better to use Flows.
That said, all of this should be moved to the view model. Then it could look like this:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _gameUiState = MutableStateFlow(GameUiState(""))
    val gameUiState: StateFlow<GameUiState> = _gameUiState.asStateFlow()

    fun ontextfieldvalChange(text: String) {
        _gameUiState.update {
            it.copy(textfieldval = it.textfieldval + "\n" + text)
        }
    }
}

Here the new text is concatenated with the previous text, with a newline (\n) as a separator. This way the previous content isn't removed, the new content is appended instead.
In your compose code you then retrieve the gameUiState with this:
val gameUiState by viewModel.gameUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

You need the gradle dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose for that.
You don't need the text variable anymore.
Now apiWithoutCompose can just call the view model's ontextfieldvalChange:
apiWithoutCompose {
    viewModel.ontextfieldvalChange(link.absUrl("href"))
}

It is a bit unclear what apiWithoutCompose is and where it is called from, but it looks like it shouldn't even be outside the view model. It probably should even be in some deeper layer, like, in a repository.
